# How do I create a symbolic link

Tags: 12.04, command-line

I was wondering how to create a symbolic link in Ubuntu (12.04 LTS). I've done this before but this time it is a little different.

This command worked before.

```
user@desktop:/media/backup/folder$ ln -sv file.ods /home/user/file.ods
```

The last time I I created a file from my backup drive [harddisk].

Now I would like to create a symbolic link to a file present on a fileserver.

This is a virtual machine and probably a network connection to it is required. The fileserver (networkshare) is mounted at /media/fileserver.

I did try to use the same command as mentioned above, however, it create an empty file when opened it askes to be deleted because it is empty and useless.

When I do the command from above, it does not work. So, can someone help me out here?

Answer (score 21):

The syntax of `ln` command is:

```
ln [options] <target file> [link name]
```

So, this command should work:

```
ln -sv /media/fileserver/anotherfile.ods /home/user/anotherfile.ods
```

The `s` option creates a symbolic link, if omitted a [hard link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_link) will be created. `v` means "be verbose", i.e. `ln` will show what it's doing.

You could also `cd` to target's directory first:

```
cd /media/fileserver
ln -sv anotherfile.ods /home/user/anotherfile.ods
```

Or `cd` to destination directory:

```
cd /home/user/
ln -sv /media/fileserver/anotherfile.ods
```

If you omit the link name, target's name is used. The above command creates a link to `/media/fileserver/anotherfile.ods` in `/home/user/anotherfile.ods`.